# Remove multiple items from array based on matched value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have issues removing items from an array based on matched value. I have an array of object like below:

```
$scope.listOfItems = [
  {productID : 1, weight: 3.5, price: 5},
  {productID : 2, weight: 4.5, price: 8},
  {productID : 3, weight: 1.5, price: 9},
  {productID : 4, weight: 2.5, price: 3},
  {productID : 5, weight: 7.5, price: 1}
];
```

And I want to remove items based on an array of productID, like below:

```
$scope.deleteList = [1,3];
```

Now I try to use two loops to check if the productID if each product is the same with any productID in the deleteList.

```
angular.forEach($scope.listOfItems , function(value, key){
    var tmp_productID = value.productID ;
    var index        = key;
    angular.forEach($scope.deleteList, function(value,key){
        if(tmp_productID === value){
            $scope.listOfItems .splice(index ,1);
        }
    });
}); 
console.log($scope.listOfItems);
```

The problem of this is, after it deletes the one with index1, the index3 will be index2, thus it will delete product2 and product5 instead of product2 and product4, which is wrong. Also the performance will be bad if I have a large number of objects in the array and I want to delete half of them. Any idea that I can delete the right record and improve the performance if possible?

Working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10726/

Comment: Do you have any problem with creating a new array rather than modifying in place?

Comment: Click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: I prefer not to create an new array, because my html has data bundling with array listOfItems

Comment: How about just a regular `for` loop in reverse?

Comment: @adeneo I believe it will the same result, because the problem comes from the index in the splice function

Comment: But if you iterate backwards, the previous indices won't change when altering the array

Comment: If your productID is unique then you should change your JSON structure to  

$scope.listOfItems = {
  1: {weight: 3.5, price: 5},
  2: {weight: 4.5, price: 8}
};

then you can directly access and delete the JSON data by product ID without looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate in reverse, that way the splicing won't affect the previous indices

```js
var $scope = {};

$scope.listOfItems = [{
    productID: 1,
    weight: 3.5,
    price: 5
}, {
    productID: 2,
    weight: 4.5,
    price: 8
}, {
    productID: 3,
    weight: 1.5,
    price: 9
}, {
    productID: 4,
    weight: 2.5,
    price: 3
}, {
    productID: 5,
    weight: 7.5,
    price: 1
}];

$scope.deleteList = [1, 3];

for ( var i = $scope.listOfItems.length; i--; ) {
    if ( $scope.deleteList.indexOf( $scope.listOfItems[i].productID ) !== -1 ) {
     $scope.listOfItems.splice(i ,1);
    }
}

console.log($scope.listOfItems);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0; max-height: 100%!important}
```

Comment: This has the same problem, please check my updated jsfiddle with your function

Comment: @Jaaaaaaay - isn't it working just fine? You know you're checking the `productID`, not the index, so `[1,4]` removes the objects with those `productID` 's ?

Comment: If you want the index instead, that's easy -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lvc0u55v/10725/